# Can a TestNG XML Build File be scheduled in Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I want to schedule a TestNG Test suite in Jenkins using the TestNG Build xml file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution is to invoke your testng.xml via a ant build.xml file, this is supported natively through Jenkins.[testng & ant](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html)